# Does a Listener require its own script?

Tags: python, windows, listener, pyautogui

I've been working on a program that does two things:

1. Takes a screenshot once a second
2. Listens for click (windows) and records the time of the click.

Here's the code for the screenshot:

```
def take_screenshot():
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot_name = str(datetime.now())
    screenshot_name = screenshot_name.replace(" ","")
    screenshot_name = screenshot_name.replace(":","")
    screenshot_name = screenshot_name.replace(".","")+".png"
    screenshot.save(screenshot_name)

def main():
    take_screenshot()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Works great.

Here's the code for the click capture using listener. I'm sure there are a ton of different ways to do this, but this is working fine for me so far:

```
CLICKS = []
def capture_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    if pressed:
        CLICKS.append(datetime.now())

with Listener(on_click=capture_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

As some of you may have noticed, I have a problem. I don't see any way to reconcile these into a single main function. If I nest the listener under the main function, then it misses clicks that happen during the time.sleep() state. Is there someway to nest the screenshot under the listener and constrain it to take a screenshot once per second? This code will likely expand, and I need to find a way to have a single main function rather than have to run two instances of python simultaneously.

Perhaps parallel processing is the answer, but I'm getting all sorts of errors with the multiprocessing library.

Comment: I would consider using either multiprocessing or multithreading. Could you please show the errors you are getting and the way you implement the multiprocessing?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working as shown below:

```
def continous_screenshot():
    while True:
        take_screenshot()

with Listener(on_click = capture_click) as listener:
    time.sleep(1)
    continous_screenshot()
    listener.join()
```

I'm sure you could do some type of multithreading too, but this was far simpler.